# using the mean() function in R to find the means of two columns in a data frame

Tags: r

I am finding it difficult to work with the mean() function to find out the mean of two columns together. When I try `mean(dat[, 2:3], na.rm = TRUE)` , where Column 2 is say, sulfate and Column 3 is say, nitrate, R throws an error message saying that argument is not numeric or logical. Just to mention that I have also tried other variants: `mean(dat[, c(2,3)], na.rm = TRUE)` and also `mean(dat[, c("sulfate","nitrate")], na.rm = TRUE)` but the same error message props up

The mean() function only works for me when used separately for each pollutant as in -

```
m1 <- mean(dat[,"sulfate"], na.rm=TRUE)

m2 <- mean(dat[,"nitrate"], na.rm=TRUE)
```

Is there a way that one could find the means of both the columns in one command avoiding an error? I think the **apply()** class of functions has a possibility and also `colMeans(datasubset[,c('sulfate','nitrate')], na.rm = TRUE)` works for me. But I am not sure as to how the function mean()could be used to solve this purpose. Any leads would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Yes. I know that colMeans works but just trying to find out if the same could be done with means() function ?

Comment: You have to apply it, i.e. `sapply(dat[2:3], mean)`

Comment: `colMeans` is much faster, it's coded in C. Why call R's `*apply` to have it call a C function, `mean`?

Comment: Thanks. Then I would stick with colMeans